# How do I permanently set the current directory to the Desktop in Python?

Tags: python

Every time I want to open a text file that's on Desktop, I always need to change the directory in Python with these commands:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir("C:/Users/Name/Desktop")
```

It's really annoying when I have to change it every time.
It's currently in `C:\\Python34`.
So how do I permanently set the working directory to Desktop?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not `PATH` you want to change, it's the current working directory.

Comment: In unix you can put `export PYTHONSTARTUP='.pythonstartup'` in .bashrc and put the commands you want to run every time in `.pythonstartup`. There is probably a Windows equivalent.

Comment: In Windows, setting environment variables (whether globally or per-user) is a control panel operation; easy enough to access.

Comment: @khelwood where can I find the unix and .bashrc?

Comment: @Brooku, what version of windows?

Comment: @Brooku, if you're using Windows, your operating system is not UNIX; completely different family. (MacOS X and Linux are major examples of popular UNIX-based operating systems). Thus, khelwood was mentioning how it would be done on a different OS, rather than the one you have.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Oh, I have Windows 8.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the line to your [PYTHONSTARTUP](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) file. So when you start an interpreter `os.chdir("C:/Users/Name/Desktop")` will be run.

I have a `startup.py` in my home directory file with the following content:

```
print("(.startup.py)")
import datetime, os, pprint, re, sys, time
print("(imported datetime, os, pprint, re, sys, time)")
```

So every time I start ipython or a python shell those lines are executed.

Not 100 percent but I imagine setting the `PYTHONSTARTUP="path_to_script"` in your environment variables on windows should do the trick with the two lines in your question in the startup file.

So for your situation you can create a file lets call it *startup.py* and inside that file you put:

```
import os
os.chdir("C:/Users/Name/Desktop")
```

Then the steps to add environment variable PYTHONSTARTUP:

For windows 8:

> From the Desktop, right-click the very bottom left corner of the screen to get the Power User Task Menu.
>
> From the Power User Task Menu, click System.
>   Click the Advanced System Settings link in the left column.
>
> Under System variables, click New.
>
> Add PYTHONSTARTUP to Variable name.
>
> Add the path of the Python file to Variable value and click OK. # <-path_to_startup.py
>
> Click OK.

Comment: Sad that you don't have `itertools` :(. This is really bad

Comment: @BhargavRao,  I meant to add a few more just got lazy!

Comment: @BhargavRao, yes but before you knew it was a lie, can't take it back now that would be rude ;)

Comment: @BhargavRao, ahem, I am awaiting a response as to which version of windows

Comment: *deletes previous comments and waits*

Comment: I added PYTHONSTARTUP as the Variable name. As the path of the python file, I typed C:\Python34 since the file is found in C:\Python34.
But I get an error everytime I open Python 3.4 Command Line

Comment: You have to pass the full path including the filename not just the directory it is in

Comment: Which filename? I don't have files of my work yet (since I'm only using the Python Command Line, what should I do?

Comment: It is working! I typed C:\Users\Name\Documents\startup.py     Since I saved the file called startup.py into Documents. Thank you very much @PadraicCunningham and everyone else!

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about isn't a PATH (list of locations to look for executable/usable files), but a Current Working Directory (CWD).

If you're using python interactively (i.e. typing in each line), you'll probably have to `chdir` or similar every time you want to run it.

If you're running a python script (a `.py` file or similar), you can place that script on the Desktop, and its CWD will be Desktop when it starts (you might be able to place a shortcut to it on the desktop and get the same behavior; I'm not as certain of that).

Alternatively, you can write that boilerplate in a script that you source/load (via PYTHONSTARTUP or the first line of your code), or move the files you're interested in (or shortcuts to them) into a place that is next to your code.